# It is safe to insulate my uninsulated oven?

Tags: insulation, oven

I have a Hotpoint gas range. I got it because it has no electronics and will probably last until the bombs fall and the ants and cockroaches take over. It is awesome, and cooks my food as well as any range can be expected to.

However, because apparently ranges with complicated and easily breakable computers are "in" right now, it was a cheap model, and I've discovered that the gas heater for the oven/broiler is totally uninsulated. So a lot of heat leaks into the kitchen, which helps during winter, but hurts during summer. The oven burner is rated at 18,000 BTUs, so it's not an insignificant amount of heat to be adding to the house for a typical one-hour bake cycle.

Therefore, I would like to insulate the burner compartment and the oven. For this, I was thinking about using spare mineral wool insulation that I have left over. This stuff is rated to more than 2,000 degrees and is totally non-combustible. It's about R-4.2 per inch, so I could probably get about R-8 or more in the hollow side panels where insulation pretty clearly goes in the more "high-end" models.

Does this sound sane?

Comment: Before you go there, be sure you are not plugging up the area where the hot gasses are supposed to flow around the oven to heat it....

Comment: Maybe use the overhead exhaust fan to remove the extra heat?  It's got to be more efficient to run that than to let the a/c deal with the excess heat.

Comment: The exhaust just recirculates inside air. Dunno why anyone makes these, since they seem pretty useless. Yet another project... In the meantime, we just open a window in the kitchen, but that sucks out un-heated air too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would not insert any insulation anywhere inside an appliance, even if you see a spot where it looks like another model is insulated. You risk starting a fire, blocking airflow or vents, trapping moisture... Also note that the broiler will get well over 2000 °F, even a normal household candle can be 2500°F. So I wouldn't necessarily consider your mineral wool safe if it is anywhere near the burner.

Possibly you could insulate the sides or back of the oven. The manual should include any clearance requirements, if any. As long as you maintain those you could be ok.